# Is there a fork or continuation of Ubuntu Builder for Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: software-recommendation, ubuntu-builder

I am looking for a fork or continuation of the Ubuntu Builder project for Ubuntu 14.04. I have had no luck building it from the source, so that is why I am looking for this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, there isn't any further Ubuntu Builder solution. I talked to the developer and he cited a couple of reasons why he discontinued the project. First, he is very busy with real life. Second, he didn't feel he was competent enough to continue the project. I didn't agree with him about the competency because his project was really brilliant and useful!

Currently, I'm using UCK (Ubuntu Customization Kit) but it seems there are systemic problems with 14.04.1 that have causes too many failures for me. For example, the installation process does not see the partitions on my 2Tb drive, which has Windows 7 and a test Linux partion. It's very strange. I have never had this issue! The other issue is that I can't install WINE 1.7.x. 14.04.1 claimes the package is broken! Perhaps this is specifically Xubuntu problems.

Try first the UCK application. If this is not good for you, perhaps you could try the hard way:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization

If anybody developer is reading this and enjoys working with Gambas 3, please help the community! Ubuntu Builder only needs a few updates to its configuration files in order to work on 14.04.1 and newer. I have tried to fix it but I can't.